# Sequelize getters do not run on model.findall( { raw:true } )

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a photo attribute in one of my Sequelize models. I have a getter for it.

```js
 photo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        get: function () {
            if (this.getDataValue("photo"))
                return process.env.IMAGE_PREFIX + this.getDataValue("photo")
            else
                return this.getDataValue("photo")
        }
    },
```

but when i want to findall records in this model with ({raw:true}) getter doesn't work.

```js
  const categories = await Category.findAll({
            limit: parseInt(limit),
            offset: parseInt(offset),
            raw: true,
            where: {
                title: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchString + '%' }
            }
        });
```

if i use ({plain:true}) instead , just finds one record.

Comment: Since V4. "Getters wont run with instance.get({ raw: true }), use instance.get({ plain: true })"  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v4/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md#others

Comment: No , it works without raw:true. It means that it works with findall

Comment: default is `raw: false` so without `raw:true`, `findAll` should call the custom getter. It says `raw: true` will bypass the custom getter when returning the response.   Besides the getter, do you have any issues?

Comment: no i don't. just getter isn't called

Comment: Right, that is what the description says.  getter should not be called when `raw: true` is applied. So if you want the getter to be called, remove `raw: true`.  Does that answer your questions?

Comment: yes, i know that but i need to use raw:true

Comment: Why do you need `raw:true`?  What do you wanna get?

Comment: when I retrieve something, a whole bunch of data is given. The only data I want is inside 'dataValues'.

Comment: You can take out `raw: true` and use `categories.map((item) => item.toJSON())` to convert the sequelize model to plain object.  This way, the custom getter is called and also you will get the plain object.

Comment: Also, the other note, you should use `order` when you use `limit`/`offset` options.  Order of records is not guaranteed and you could get unexpected pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to newer version of `sequelize` as documentation itself says:

> Getters wont run with `instance.get({ raw: true })`, use `instance.get({ plain: true })`

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/ec7c474028e7a2a4b4e10b48e8109e23fbfb1fb3)